# Retrieve common paths of polylines ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, polygon, intersection, line

I have a polygon featureClass and a polyline featureClass. I now want to handle all geometries within the latter that are contained in the boundaries of polygon features, that means they shell simply touch the polygons boundary. This accords to the simple "select features from  that share a line segment from " -operator within the "select by location"-tool.
But how to achieve this with ArcObjects? I already tried the following:

```
IPolyline reshaper = ...;  
ITopologicalOperator topo = (ITopologicalOperator) singlePolygon;  
IGeometry boundary = topo.Boundary;  
IRelationalOperator relOp1 = (IRelationalOperator) boundary;  
if (relOp1.Contains(reshaper)) {...}
```

I also worked with the horrible Relation-Method which is intended to use on more complex queries. I tried it with `relOp1.Relation(reshaper, "g1 contains g2")` but simply received a meaningless HRESULT-Error of kind `ARCWEB_E_INVALID_RING_CALCULATION_TYPE` if I looked up the errorlist from ArcoBjects correctly (which I cannot ensure...).

So what now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came across the issue by two simple steps:

1. select the features that touch the request geometry
2. perform a spatial contains-query on every segment within the request geometry

These done I receive every feature that shares a line-segment with the request-geometry

The following code achieves this:

```
ISpatialFilter filter = new SpatialFilterClass();  
filter.Geometry = this.Geometry;  
filter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelTouches;       // select all features that touch the request-geometry  
filter.GeometryField = this.mFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;

// perform the query
IFeatureCursor cursor = this.mFeatureClass.Search(filter, false);

// build the slaves

IFeature feature;
while ((feature = cursor.NextFeature()) != null) {
    IRowBuffer buffer = feature;
    bool foundSegment = false;
    // only select "true" touching geometries (geometries that not just share one single point)

    ISegmentCollection segments = (ISegmentCollection) this.Geometry;
    for (int i = 0; i < segments.SegmentCount; i++) {
        IPolyline curSegment = new PolylineClass();                 // the current segment as a high-lvl-geometry to use as IRelationalOperator
        ((ISegmentCollection) curSegment).AddSegment(segments.get_Segment(i));

        ITopologicalOperator topo = (ITopologicalOperator) feature.Shape;
        IRelationalOperator relOp = (IRelationalOperator) topo.Boundary;
        if (relOp.Contains(curSegment)) {                           // current segment is contained in the feature
            foundSegment = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (foundSegment) {
        // do whatever you want to if you got a feature
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the GIS stack exchange.

The topological operator is typically used to construct new geometries. It sounds to me like you just want to iterate through some features that share a boundary. In that case I would start a loop that iterates through each polygon feature. Within the polygon feature loop you can call a method something like this:

```
private IFeatureCursor ReturnSpatialQuery(IFeatureClass inFeatureClass, IGeometry searchGeometry, esriSpatialRelEnum enumSpatialRel, string sWhere)
    {
        //SET UP SPATIAL FILTER
        ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
        spatialFilter.Geometry = searchGeometry;
        spatialFilter.GeometryField = inFeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
        spatialFilter.SpatialRel = enumSpatialRel;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sWhere)) spatialFilter.WhereClause = sWhere;

        //PERFORM THE QUERY
        return inFeatureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
    }
```

The inFeatureClass would be your polyline class, the searchGeometry is the polygon shape, and you can also add a where clause for filtering attributes. Pass the type of spatial relationship you want from the esri constants. This method will return a feature cursor that you can then iterate through in your main loop and do something with each polyline.

Comment: I think I did not express me the right way. I actually know how to build a spatial query (no matter if If use a spatial filter on the featureClass or a simple comparison-method like `IRelationOperator#contains`). The problem is actually finding the right spatial condition for the purpose.

Comment: May I know why you downmarked the question?